# Writing (A && C) || (B && C) conditional shorter

Tags: perl, logic

(E.G. In Perl) When either condition A or condition B have the same consequence

```
if (A){
    # Consequence X
}elsif (B){
    # Consequence X
}
```

we can write

```
if ( A || B ) {
     # Consequence X
}
```

How about we have the following condition: Either when A and C are true, or B and C are true, consequence C follows.

This can be written very long:

```
if ( A && C){
      # Consequence X
} elsif (B && C ){
      # consequence X
}
```

My question is, is there any way to write this shorter?
Something like this:

```
if ( (A && C) || (B && C) )
```

is syntactically ok ???

Comment: Correct but `if ((A || B) && C)`

Comment: It would have been faster to test than to post this question! There are three variables with effectively two values each (true and false), meaning there are only eight cases to test (2*2*2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

```
if ( A && C){
      # Consequence X
} elsif (B && C ){
      # consequence X
}
```

is the same as:

```
if ( (A && C) || (B && C) ){
    #Consequence X
}
```

And this avoids evaluating `C` twice:

```
if ( (A || B) && C){
    #Consequence X
}
```

BTW, this is more like a logical question, the logic here isn't limited to Perl.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
if (C && (A || B)) {
}
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily the same.  It evaluates C even if both A and B are false, which might not be safe.

Comment: Sure, it evaluates `C` first. And it seems to be more optimal as when it failes no `A` or `B` evaluated.